# iOS Push Notification on Production Not Working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working with push notifications and like 2-3 weeks ago they were working fine on production and dev, but now they stopped working on Production. 
I revoked and generated new certificates and provision profiles, but still not working on production. 
If I use the dev certificate/provision profile they work.
On production I don't receive any notifications and that's the problem.
Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: describe your Error ?

Comment: I don't get any error. The APNS doesn't seem to work on Production because on Dev when I run directly from XCode they work fine.
I checked all the certificates/provision profiles and they are all enable and configured to use push notifications.

Comment: What about the bundle identifier, have you made any changes to that?

Comment: @sanandiyavipul just tested with APN Tester Software and I can get the notifications. Maybe the problem is from the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check that What is problem u have ?

You use a APN Tester software to check for notification is get or not ?
You can DownLoad APN Tester here => [APN Tester for MAC](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12)

1. Using APN Tester notification is get then Problem with your backend **Backend problem**.
2. Using APN Tester Notification is not get then problem with your **Certificates**.

Comment: I get the notification using the APN Tester, so its probably Backend side